# Anyone remember a sci-fi character named Saa?

Tags: story-identification, character-identification

Does anyone remember a sci-fi character named 'Saa'?

He's from a book back in the 1960s, I believe, maybe '70s.

Comment: Can you remember anything about the book aside from the character name? Was Saa a human or an alien? Was the book for adults or young adults or children? What did Saa do, were they the hero or a villain, etc

Comment: Yes!That's it! I've been wondering about the name of the book for years. One of my faves from my teen years. Loaned it out and never got it back. He was found in a cave, encased in a block of some sort of stone after being put into a sleep state. I think his civilization was under threat from people in the core of the earth. He took his human friends who found him back with him to help him save his civilization. Going to Amazon now to find it!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209212/teenagers-find-an-ancient-lizard-creature-in-stasis-and-accompany-him-on-adventu (which is newer but has an answer confirmed by OP comment)

Answer (score 12):

Could this be the 1970 science-fantasy novel "[Stranger From the Depths](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2349510.Stranger_From_the_Depths)" by Gerry Turner?

> The star of the book is a lizard man named Saa, a friendly survivor of
>   a dying race of amphibian people who live deep below the Earth. He
>   takes some human kids to this fantasy world, which is, as best I can
>   recall, well described